# Requesting help in jQuery or CSS.

Tags: css, jquery-ui

The background color, font color and border are being lost when I drop an element. 
How do I keep these properties intact? Here is the project in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n2learning/tV4n7/48/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed a minor change to your CSS.  I've removed the #routinefilter from this rule so it applies to all `.droptrue` elements, no matter what their parent element is:

```
.droptrue{
    background: lightgray;
    color: navy;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #666;
}
```

Here's the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tV4n7/49/).

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS rule:

```
#routinefilter .droptrue{
```

only applies to elements with a class `droptrue` WHILE they are in the container `routinefilter`. Once you drop them in the box, they are no longer inside `routinefilter` and the rule doesn't apply. Try changing that to just:

```
.droptrue{
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector was specific to the point of origin, but not to the dropping-point. Add `#dropTargetframe .droptrue` to your selector, to give:

```
#routinefilter .droptrue,
#dropTargetframe .droptrue {
    background: lightgray;
    color: navy;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #666;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tV4n7/50/).

Or you could simply remove the ancestor `id` from the selector, to give simply:

```
.droptrue {
    background: lightgray;
    color: navy;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #666;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tV4n7/52/).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
#routinefilter .droptrue, #dropTargetframe .droptrue{
    background: lightgray;
    color: navy;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #666;
}
```

The .droptrue elements will keep the same css style when inside the box as well!

**Edit:**
You can also change it to only `.droptrue` if you want those boxes to use this style wherever they are.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    #routinefilter .droptrue
```

into

```
    .droptrue
```

Edit: Whoops, too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to CSS

```
.droptrue
{
    font: 16px serif 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgray;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    color: navy;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```